# IOS delay I cant figure out using AVFoundation to scan barcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a time issue that has had me stumped I though since I was using a delegate to send the data back to the HomeView to process and redirect out to the ScanResults that was the issue but even if I

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScanResultsSegue" sender:self];
```

directly to it I still see a huge delay till the ScanResultsView comes up. Here is the NSLog. Last to lines show the delay

```
2014-05-24 16:20:55.640 selfcheckin[2748:60b] StartReading Called
2014-05-24 16:21:03.519 selfcheckin[2748:3603] We have a QR -> performSelectorOnMainThread
2014-05-24 16:21:03.522 selfcheckin[2748:3603] IsMainThread: NO
2014-05-24 16:21:03.549 selfcheckin[2748:3603] Barcode: {"stop_id":"3","event_id":"1"}
2014-05-24 16:21:03.555 selfcheckin[2748:3603] didScan Delegate called!
2014-05-24 16:21:03.576 selfcheckin[2748:3603] Parsing Json Dictionary
2014-05-24 16:21:03.584 selfcheckin[2748:3603] Event_id: 1
2014-05-24 16:21:03.590 selfcheckin[2748:3603] Stop_id: 3
2014-05-24 16:21:03.603 selfcheckin[2748:3603] Account_id: 4
2014-05-24 16:21:04.782 selfcheckin[2748:60b] StopReading Called
2014-05-24 16:21:14.721 selfcheckin[2748:3603] Made it to Success!!!
```

Its taking 10 seconds to transition to the ScanResultsPage .......... I cant find what would be causing it in my code.  Should it take that long??  Relevant parts to the

```
- (BOOL)startReading {
    NSError *error;

    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }

    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [_captureSession addInput:input];

    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;
    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];

    _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
    [_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.layer.bounds];
    [_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];

    [_captureSession startRunning];
    NSLog(@"%@",@"StartReading Called");
    return YES;
}

-(void)stopReading{
    [_captureSession stopRunning];
    _captureSession = nil;
    [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    NSLog(@"%@",@"StopReading Called");
}

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {
        AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
            NSLog(@"We have a QR -> performSelectorOnMainThread");
            NSLog(@"IsMainThread: %@", ([NSThread isMainThread]) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
             _isReading = NO;
            NSLog(@"Barcode: %@",[(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadataObj stringValue]);
            //NSLog(@"Now performSegueWithIdentifier");
            //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScanResultsSegue" sender:self];
            NSLog(@"didScan Delegate called!");
            [self.scandelegate didScan:self barcodedata:[(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadataObj stringValue]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write the code in the View Controller that "ScanResultsSegue" goes to, or is it from another project?

Comment: Its a one I added with just an nslog in viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of issue is just about always caused by trying to talk to the interface on a background thread. All communication with the interface *must* be on the main thread.

In general your code is quite incoherent with regard to threads. You can see this from your logging, which shows two different threads (the main thread and a background thread) interleaved. Notice also that this is nonsensical and dangerous:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
_isReading = NO;
```

You are now accessing `_isReading` from within a background thread, so you are likely to have contention between threads for this ivar. Moreover, you're lying; you *are* still reading, since `stopReading` has not been called yet (as the logging shows): `waitUntilDone` is NO so the code immediately goes on, and `stopReading` is called on the main thread much later. Everything is out of order and helter-skelter.

You know that `captureOutput:` is being called on a background thread, so at that point you need to start being very, very careful. The safest thing, if you have no reason to be on a background thread, is to step yourself out to the main thread immediately (`dispatch_async`) so that the rest of that method executes on the main thread. If you do have reason to be on a background thread, then at least make sure you don't do thread-unsafe things, as you are evidently doing now.

Comment: Sorry I was going off a tutorial located here [http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/)  and the calls are still in the correct order.  I am new to Objective C as I mainly write Java and PHP but our Cordova based app sucks visually so I am trying to rewrite native apps. This one part is holding me up. I guess I will go look for a better tutorial